# enable access to elastic beanstalk from only from specific IP's

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

my Node.Js application is hosted in AWS EB.I want to restrict access so that only certain IP's can consume my Node.Js services.
How can i enable EB only to visible to certian IP's?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can whitelist the set of ips in the security group attached to the loadbalancer in your Elastic Beanstalk environment.

Comment: So only those ip's will get access?

Comment: Yes only the whitelisted ips will have access. You can also give it in CIDR notation for large set of ips in a network.

Comment: Can you tell me where to find this configuration? I have a load balanaced elastic beanstalk.But i cant find no where to configure the load balancer.

Comment: Go to EC2 console and select load balancer. In its properties you should be able to find the security group

Comment: Is it in the VPC?

Comment: You can access the security groups from vpc also. Need to find the one assigned to the ELB.